# node.js to c++ protocol buffers

Tags: c++, node.js, protocol-buffers

I create a protocol buffer in node.js and I want to decode it in a node c++ addon.

In node, I create the buffer and send it to the c++ addon:

```
var Message = root.lookupType(tutorial.AddressBook);
var payload = { people: [{name: "name", id: 23, email: "sdfsdf", phones: [{ number: "12", type: 1}], last_updated: 3}]};

var errMsg = Message.verify(payload);
if (errMsg)
    throw Error(errMsg);

var message = Message.create(payload); 

var buffer = Message.encode(message).finish();
const cppResult = addons.myNanMethod(buffer);
```

How am I then supposed to decode this in c++? ParseFromString doesn't help. I get a runtime error "node: symbol lookup error:path/to/my/addon."

```
char* data = (char*) node::Buffer::Data(info[0]->ToObject());
std::string datastring data, node::Buffer::Length(info[0])););

// Verify that the version of the library that we linked against is
// compatible with the version of the headers we compiled against.
GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

tutorial::AddressBook address_book;
{
    // Read the existing address book.
    if (!address_book.ParseFromString(&datastring)) {
        cerr << "Failed to parse address book." << endl;
        errorCode = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `data` has a null character, then `std::string datastring(data);` will be missing some information. Try using `std::string datastring(data, length);` where length comes from `node::Buffer::Length`

Comment: @kmdreko unfortunately this doesn't help. :(